# How to properly convert MemoryStream to Array

Tags: c#, .net

I have implemented a code block in order to convert Stream into Byte Array. And code snippet is shown below. But unfortunately, it gives OutOfMemory Exception while converting MemoryStream to Array (return newDocument.ToArray();). please could someone help me with this?

```
public byte[] MergeToBytes()
    {
        using (var processor = new PdfDocumentProcessor())
        {
            AppendStreamsToDocumentProcessor(processor);
            using (var newDocument = new MemoryStream())
            {
                processor.SaveDocument(newDocument);
                return newDocument.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

public Stream MergeToStream()
    {

        return new MemoryStream(MergeToBytes());
        

    }
```

Comment: With the exception of the try and missing catch that code does not throw an `OutOfMemoryException`. It looks like the actual code that is throwing the Exception is not shown. Please create an [mcve] that actually replicates the problem. See also [ask].

Comment: Do note that depending on what you are actually doing the Exception might be accurate meaning if you were to access a stream to a large movie file and then read it into a byte array you could run into a memory limitation which would then throw that exception type.

Comment: Need more code. What are you writing to the memory stream? How many bytes? Why do you need the array? How will you use it later? But the best way to get an answer is providing a reproducible example.

Comment: How much data is stored in the memory stream? What are your memory constraints, i.e. how much memory is available to your C# process?

Comment: you should not be calling `ToArray` on your `MemoryStream`.  Here is some information from MS Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=netcore-3.1 -- I will publish an answer with an example